# UserControl in asp .net is not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-controls

I have created a two usercontrols in asp.net and one webform . Now i want these two usercontrols to show in form in webform but it say that `there must be one head with runat="server"`

this is webform where i am using UserControl!

```
            <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Light.master"  CodeBehind="AdministrationPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="DXApplication5.AdministrationPage" %>
        <%@ Register src="~/AdminPage/AssignmentTab.ascx" tagname="AssignmentUC" tagprefix="uc1" %>
          <asp:Content ID="MainContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
        <table border="0">

<tr>
<td>
<div class="accountHeader">
     <uc1:AssignmentUC ID="CalendarUserControl1" runat="server" />  
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</asp:Content>
```

This is UserControl below:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"  ClassName="AssignmentUC" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AssignmentTab.ascx.cs" Inherits="DXApplication5.AdminPage.AssignmentTab" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a single form to your masterpage, this may be the cause of your error.

I would also remove all other form server controls from your user controls and pages.

Try these steps:

1. Go to `Light.master` master page file and make sure that this is in there somewhere `<form id="form1" runat="server">` and a closing tag, the id may be different.
2. Go to the following files `AssignmentTab.ascx` and `AdministrationPage.aspx` and remove any `<form id="form1" runat="server">` and closing tags `</form>`

Comment: You haven't posted the full code, I will try and add without it.

Comment: that's strange that i have only one form and it still not doing well :(

Comment: I have guests at home right now can i continue questioning here later? Please bear with me.

Comment: same that there is runat= servrer more than one. i have voted up your answer.

Comment: There has to be nested controls under calendar or another. Please post the markup for them.

Answer (score 0):

Check user control code if it contains a head element. Also check all dependencies to see if there are head elements present in them.

Comment: i need to mention head - Now? :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you have use `<form id="formID" runat="server">` in both of your page and user Control .
Just remove `runat="server"` from your user Control Form tag .

Comment: No i just have added one form in master page -

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have in your user control cs file:

```
public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

In ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebUserControl1" %>
```

In aspx parent:

```
    <%@ Register  Src="WebUserControl1.ascx" TagPrefix="uc" TagName="WebUserControl1 " %>

 <uc:WebUserControl1  runat="server" ID="mycontrol" />
```